# Cliente-Servidor entre APP que trackeia localização em tempo real

Tags: android, arquitetura-de-software, cliente-servidor

Olá, possuímos um app que envia a cada 15 segundos a localização dos usuários para o servidor. Atualmente é um POST simples da (lat/lng) na API, haveria uma outra forma melhor de se fazer isso?

Alguma arquitetura específica?

Answer (score 1):

Não creio que haja uma arquitetura específica para isso, vou só fazer algumas recomendações.

É interessante guardar as posições dentro de uma tabela no SQLite dentro do próprio app para os momentos em que não há internet disponível e descarregá-las no servidor quando houver. É a chamada bufferização. Sugiro o seguinte procedimento:

A cada 15 segundos:

- Captura uma posição;
- Guarda na tabela;
- Se houver Internet, faz um select trazendo as (digamos) cinquenta últimas posições e tenta enviá-las ao servidor.

Atenção para a data-hora da captura, ela é diferente da data-hora de envio e da data-hora da chegada no servidor. Talvez seja interessante para vocês tratar esses valores como coisas distintas.

De resto, a abordagem parece ok.

Considere guardar o máximo de informações que puder sobre cada posição (data-hora, lat, lng, altitude, velocidade, direção, IMEI ou outro identificador do aparelho, etc), pode ser que sejam úteis um dia.

Se o número de usuários crescer muito, pode ser preciso tomar cuidado com a frequência de envio para não sobrecarregar o servidor (reduzir para um intervalo entre um e cinco minutos, por exemplo).

Comment: @piozevan, estamos com dificuldades nos horários de pico, onde os motoristas estão realizando corridas com mais frequência e o tempo que é enviado a localização para o servidor passa a ser 15 segundos...